# The code couldn't traverse through dropdown menu

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

I want to click a dropdown menu and check if the page of every link is has valid content or not by checking the page's title.

if the page title is "Under Construction: Mercury Tours", then the link has invalid content. Otherwise, valid content.

My procedure:
 1.store xpaths of all the valid links in a String array "xpath".
  2.Traverse through the string array and check the title with the predefined invalid page's title.

step 1 is good and I can see the all the xpaths getting printed. The problem comes with the second step. The code cannot traverse through the String array and click each link.  Please help.

```
package pack1;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;


public class CheckEveryDropDownLink {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String baseURL = "http://demo.guru99.com/test/newtours/";
    String underConsTitle = "Under Construction: Mercury Tours";                    
    int size=0;
    String[] xpath = new String[20];
    String temp;
    String tempxpath;




    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get(baseURL);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='navbar-brand-
centered']/ul/li[1]/a")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    tempxpath=".//*[@id='navbar-brand-centered']/ul/li[1]/a";




    for(int i=1,j=0;i<21 ;i++)
    {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='navbar-brand-
centered']/ul/li[1]/a")).click();
     temp= ".//*[@id='navbar-brand-centered']/ul/li[1]/ul/li[" + i + "]/a";
    if(driver.findElement(By.xpath(temp)).isEnabled())
    {
     xpath[j] = temp;
     System.out.println(xpath[j]);
     j++;
    }
    }

    for(int i=1;i<21;i++)
    {
        String xp=xpath[i];
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='navbar-brand-
centered']/ul/li[1]/a")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(xp)).click();
        if(driver.getTitle().equals(underConsTitle))
        {
            System.out.println("The page has invalid content");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("The page has valid content");
        }
        driver.navigate().back();
    }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
1520964562367   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.19.1 
(0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 2017-10-31)
1520964562374   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:32329
1520964562778   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program 
Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-profile" 
"C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.RrB8rmJsgtnf"
1520964564749   Marionette  INFO    Enabled via --marionette
1520964570359   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 28399
1520964570656   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored 
for this session
Mar 13, 2018 11:39:30 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake 
createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
JavaScript warning: https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-1248015-
24, line 69: unreachable code after return statement
JavaScript warning: https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-1248015-
24, line 69: unreachable code after return statement
.//*[@id='navbar-brand-centered']/ul/li[1]/ul/li[1]/a
.//*[@id='navbar-brand-centered']/ul/li[1]/ul/li[2]/a
.//*[@id='navbar-brand-centered']/ul/li[1]/ul/li[3]/a
.//*[@id='navbar-brand-centered']/ul/li[1]/ul/li[4]/a
.//*[@id='navbar-brand-centered']/ul/li[1]/ul/li[5]/a
.//*[@id='navbar-brand-centered']/ul/li[1]/ul/li[6]/a
.//*[@id='navbar-brand-centered']/ul/li[1]/ul/li[7]/a
.//*[@id='navbar-brand-centered']/ul/li[1]/ul/li[8]/a
.//*[@id='navbar-brand-centered']/ul/li[1]/ul/li[9]/a
.//*[@id='navbar-brand-centered']/ul/li[1]/ul/li[10]/a
.//*[@id='navbar-brand-centered']/ul/li[1]/ul/li[11]/a
.//*[@id='navbar-brand-centered']/ul/li[1]/ul/li[12]/a
.//*[@id='navbar-brand-centered']/ul/li[1]/ul/li[13]/a
.//*[@id='navbar-brand-centered']/ul/li[1]/ul/li[14]/a
.//*[@id='navbar-brand-centered']/ul/li[1]/ul/li[15]/a
.//*[@id='navbar-brand-centered']/ul/li[1]/ul/li[16]/a
.//*[@id='navbar-brand-centered']/ul/li[1]/ul/li[17]/a
.//*[@id='navbar-brand-centered']/ul/li[1]/ul/li[18]/a
.//*[@id='navbar-brand-centered']/ul/li[1]/ul/li[19]/a
.//*[@id='navbar-brand-centered']/ul/li[1]/ul/li[20]/a
Exception in thread "main" 
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element <a 
href="../../test/radio.html"> could not be scrolled into view
Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-
01T19:05:14.666Z'
System info: host: 'CHANDU', ip: '192.168.116.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', 
os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_112'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, 
browserVersion: 58.0, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: 
false, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 3132, moz:profile: 
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local..., moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: 
normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, platformVersion: 10.0, rotatable: 
false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}}
Session ID: 6ebc7f47-3619-4e22-9a0f-79684bb7c5e3
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at
```

org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:279)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:83)
    at pack1.CheckEveryDropDownLink.main(CheckEveryDropDownLink.java:64)

Comment: Are you getting any errors or exceptions?

Comment: output is posted in the question.

Comment: Why are you navigating back, what happens when you remove this statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

I removed the driver.navigate().back() and moved the click on the dropdown in the last loop to the end of the loop, otherwise the dropdown is closed at the beginning of the loop and the links are not visible.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

String baseURL = "http://demo.guru99.com/test/newtours/";
String underConsTitle = "Under Construction: Mercury Tours";
int size = 0;
String[] xpath = new String[20];
String temp;
String tempxpath;

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get(baseURL);

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='navbar-brand- centered']/ul/li[1]/a")).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

tempxpath = ".//*[@id='navbar-brand-centered']/ul/li[1]/a";

for (int i = 1, j = 0; i < 21; i++) 
{

    temp = ".//*[@id='navbar-brand-centered']/ul/li[1]/ul/li[" + i + "]/a";
    if (driver.findElement(By.xpath(temp)).isEnabled()) 
       {
          xpath[j] = temp;
          System.out.println(xpath[j]);
          j++;
        }
}

for (int i = 1; i < 21; i++) 
{
    String xp = xpath[i];

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(xp)).click();
    if (driver.getTitle().equals(underConsTitle)) 
    {
        System.out.println("The page has invalid content");
    } else 
    {
        System.out.println("The page has valid content");
     }
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='navbar-brand-centered']/ul/li[1]/a")).click();
}}
```

Comment: Thanks. I got the logic now.

Comment: Now I can traverse through all the links in the dropdown menu.

Comment: I've added another click in the first for loop so that the opened dropdown menu will be closed and saw the output. the dropdown is left opened at the end of the run. so I added another click outside after the for loop to close the opened dropdown menu. So now I have to open the dropdown menu to click a link in it. Added that in the second for loop. After I click the sixth link in the dropdown menu some error is happening. I think the fault is with the site functionality. The test run ends at that sixth link. So I navigated back at the end of the loop to avoid that. Worked.

Comment: Glad I could help you.